# Hibernate 4 Multi-Tenancy and Spring 3 Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

All

I was evaluating Multi-Tenancy feature present in Hibernate 4(4.1.0) along with Spring 3(3.1.0), but was not able to get it working with HibernateTransaction setting. I have defined settings as follows.

**LocalSessionFactoryBean :**

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Inject private DataSource dataSource;
    @Inject private MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException{
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        bean.setPackagesToScan("com");
        bean.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        bean.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.multiTenancy", "SCHEMA");
        bean.getHibernateProperties().put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl());
        bean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        return bean;
    }

}
```

**Configuration.xml :**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.green" />


    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}" p:user="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
        p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100"
        p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="com.green.saas.hibernate.SaasHibernateTransactionManager"
        depends-on="sessionFactory" >
          <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

If I use plain HibernateTransactionManager provided by spring 3 I get error tenant identifier not set, reason for this being, it opens a session as follows

1. `Session newSession = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(getSessionFactory( ));`
2. `(Session) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(openSessionMethod, sessionFactory)` in `openSession` method
3. `Method openSessionMethod = ClassUtils.getMethod(SessionFactory.class, "openSession")` above `openSessionMethod` argument is defined as.

we can see that there is no hook where you can provide tenant-identifier as expected while opening a session with tenant-identifier e.g

```
Session newSession = getSessionFactory().withOptions().tenantIdentifier ( "abc" ).openSession();
```

or

```
class instance provided by hibernate property "hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" is called by which session is provided with tenant identifier.
```

To overcome this I extended class HibernateTransactionManager and override method doBegin and where new session is opened I opened it

```
getSessionFactory().withOptions().tenantIdentifier ( "abc" ).openSession();
```

this makes thing click and work.

**I just wanted to know, is this above approach fine or there is some setting that I am not aware of that makes it work out of the box.**

Thanks in advance.

Hibernate - 4.1.0
Spring - 3.1.0

Comment: is it possible to show how everything works in a sample maven app? I will really appreciate if you share it with us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this feature was buggy on `Hibernate` side with the version you used: [SPR-9222](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9222), [HHH-7306](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7306).

Starting from `Hibernate` version `4.1.4` You should use [`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4686) to pass the current tenant ID to `SessionFactory`.